# Does Postfix add the DKIM header before or after a message is queued?

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-18.04, dkim, queue

The Postfix configuration has been changed to add a DKIM header when sending a mail.

But Postfix is currently in the `stop` status, and `mailq` shows that new mails have been queuing in the meantime.

Will `postfix start` make Postfix add the DKIM header to these queued messages, or are these already processed and will be sent *without* the new DKIM header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`opendkim` interacts with `postfix` through `Milter` interface and `Milter` interactions happen before a message is queued. See [MILTER_README](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).

Comment: Is there any way to have postfix "replay" the queue to add the DKIM header?

Comment: Possible but complicated. You can send all messages to another temporary postfix instance and then back to the original postfix instance. But you'll need to check for mail loop protection. Probably it deserves a separate question.

Comment: Ok thanks, my only fear is that the few mails queued (~10) will not pass other MTAs and trigger a spam listing, even if DMARC is set to "none" action(?).

Comment: I wouldn't expect a message to be classified as spam just because it doesn't have a DKIM signature. For example, Spamassassin score for DMARC_NONE is 0.1